# how to make search and form category merges like amazon on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to make form search merges with form category like on the amazon.com page.

I've tried to make it, and yes I'm using bootstrap, but seems looks like weird because both of them have rounded corners,

this some of my code

```
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
       <label for="inputState"></label>
          <select id="category" class="form-control">
               <option selected>All Departements</option>
               <option>...</option>
           </select>

        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
```

I expect that form search and form category merges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your form-fields that you want to merge in a class `.input-group`. Take reference from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/

Your html would then be:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
   <div class="input-group">
       <label for="inputState"></label>
          <select id="category" class="form-control">
               <option selected>All Departements</option>
               <option>...</option>
           </select>

        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

to make to borders rounded you can add custom styles:

```
.form-inline .input-group .form-control.left-round {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.form-inline .input-group .form-control.right-round {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

and add these classes(`.right-round`, `.left-round`) to the html as below:

```
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
   <div class="input-group">
       <label for="inputState"></label>
          <select id="category" class="form-control left-round">
               <option selected>All Departements</option>
               <option>...</option>
           </select>

        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 right-round" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: woww, thankyou man, I think, I need to read more of the documentation hehe,now I'm done with my college assignments